# Turning off Warning/Errors for ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, exception, routes, silex

I have a Silex error, that repeats 4 times. I Would like to resolve or hide it. The page loads normally, otherwise.

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php on line 96
```

Followed by:

```
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /es/blah" in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php on line 145
```

I am testing an error page for a route that doesn't exist. Here is my '$app->error()'

```
$app->error(function(\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
    switch ($code) {
        case 404:
            return $app['twig']->render('error.twig', array(
                'errormessage' => 'Sorry. This page does not exist.',
            ));
            break;
        default:
            return $app['twig']->render('error.twig', array(
                'errormessage' => 'There has been an error.',
            ));
            break;
    }
});
```

My OS is CentOS 6.5 and PHP 5.3.3 with Silex 1.2.3 I believe. Turning on `error_reporting(0)` in my `index.php` does not work. I also have Xdebug installed, for reference.

Comment: are you in debug mode? $app['debug'] = true;?

Comment: I wasn't, but I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've figured this out. As said above, I was getting messages about Exception handling, but Silex and `$app->error(Exception $e)` should catch exceptions.

In fact, exceptions were thrown and being caught properly.

In my original question, I mention `Xdebug`, which was the problem. `Xdebug` has a setting `xdebug.show_exception_trace` that when set to `1`, shows exceptions no matter what.

This was in my `php.ini`. To fix it, I had to remove it.

Now, all is well.